# REST API to update test point execution outcome in Azure Devops using Test Case ID or Test Case Name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Currently I am able to change the outcome of a test point using it's testpointID in the API.Below is the API:
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planID}/Suites/{suiteID}/points/{testpointID}?api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/test/Plans/%7BplanID%7D/Suites/%7BsuiteID%7D/points/%7BtestpointID%7D?api-version=5.0)

According to my understanding, the test point IDs are uniquely generated by the system and the only way to know them is through another REST API.(please correct me if I am wrong)

Since obtaining the test point IDs through another API call is an additional step, I would like to know if there is any way to make the first outcome updation call using the test case name or test case ID?

Comment: It's really stupid how Microsoft designed it so that you need to reference a Test Point in the API to update a test case.  Nobody refers to a test case by its Test Point; the test point isn't even visually found in a Test Case's details on the UI.  Ridiculous design.

Microsoft should follow TestRail's footsteps to develop a great test case management tool.  Excuse my rant but I spent so much timing trying to figure out how to get this working only to find their shitty API's limitations.

Comment: What I'm doing, for now is.... this: Getting the TestPointID


${azureAPIBaseURL}/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/${planId}/Suites/${suitId}/TestPoint?testCaseId=${testCaseID}&api-version=6.0-preview.2


And then updating: ${azureAPIBaseURL}/${organization}/${project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/${planId}/Suites/${suitId}/TestPoint?api-version=6.0-preview.2`


Using a PAT from my azure account

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a test point, it's supposed to get a test run. So you could try [Results - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to update test results in a test run:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but obtaining the latest run ID is another additional step which I am trying to avoid. I am looking for a way to use the existing known variables for the updation REST call.

Comment: Is there any way to update the latest run results without actually using the runId ? That will solve my problem too!!

Comment: Unfortunately,  there is no latest option. But when you select the test run in Test Plans -- Runs, you could see the runId in the url.

Comment: Not resolved yet. Still looking for a way to execute and update the outcome using the known variables like test case ID etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't see such api right now.